# How to make a Java class implementing multiple interfaces easier to read

Tags: java, coding-style, multiple-inheritance

For example, in the following code, A implements interfaces I1, I2, ... In, and overrides their methods. But I found in A, it is a bit hard to read, and understand which methods are from which interfaces. Is there a better way to make the code easier to read?

```
class A implements I1, I2, ..., In {

   @Override
   void methoda_in_I1() ...

   @Override
   void methodb_in_I1() ...

   @Override
   void methoda_in_I2() ...

   @Override
   void methodb_in_I2() ...

   ...

   @Override
   void methoda_in_In() ...

   @Override
   void methodb_in_In() ...
```

}

Comment: u can use InetrfaceName with methods if u re creating your own interface. but if u r using bulin then u need to face this problem, bcos i dont think the entire architecture will be changed for this problem, comments are here, use them to indicate the method's inetrface name.

Comment: @JoeC I don't think there's a way.

Comment: @JoeC you can use javadoc of the superclass.

Comment: Why do you need to know which method is from which interface? What if 2 interfaces have a method with the same signature? If it is only for navigation reasons then any modern IDE will provide a way to link to the super method of a method. For example Netbeans will show an icon, that looks like a circle with an 'I', next to the line with @Override to the right of the editor

Answer (score 1):

Instead of grouping methods by interface, use a simple sorting technique: the alphabet.

By this, I mean, list the methods in the class alphabetically.

Native english speakers understand the alphabet and the alphabet is the "natural" sort order for native english speakers.  Here is an example: which is easier to understand, a phone book that lists people based on their address or a phone book that lists people alphabetically by their name.

If you are using eclipse, click on the method name and hit alt + shift + J for an automatic comment that will reference the interface (or base class) method that is being overridden.

Answer (score 0):

There is no real easy way to deal with this. Best I could think of was using comments to identify the interface you are overriding like this:

```
@Override//Interface A
public void methodFromA() {
    ...
}

@Override//Interface B
public void methodFromB() {
    ...
}
```